# How to make custom template filter case insensitive? (Django 2.1)

Tags: django

My custom template filter highlights keyword put into my search engine in the results page, just like on Google.

Search engine code:

```
def query_search(request):
    articles = cross_currents.objects.all()
    search_term = ''
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['keyword']
        articles = articles.annotate(similarity=Greatest(TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term), TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term))).filter(similarity__gte=0.03).order_by('-similarity')
    context = {'articles': articles, 'search_term': search_term}
    return render(request, 'query_search.html', context)
```

Custom filter code:

```
register = template.Library()
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def highlight(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    return mark_safe(value.replace(search_term, "<span class='highlight'>%s</span>" % search_term))
```

HTML template:

```
<ul>
{% for article in articles %}
<li><a href="{% url 'search:article_detail' article.ArticleID %}">{{ article|highlight:search_term }}</a></li>
<p> {{ article.Content|highlight:search_term|truncatewords:2000 }} </p>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The result is that the filter only highlights the text that exactly matches the case of the input keyword. If the user types "korean war", the filter will not highlight "Korean War". How can I make my filter case insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use regular expression to achieve this.

Example:

```
import re

def highlight(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    # first compile the regex pattern using the search_term
    pattern = re.compile(re.escape(search_term), re.IGNORECASE)

    # now replace
    new_value = pattern.sub('<span class="highlight">\g<0></span>', value)
    return mark_safe(new_value)
```

Comment: Thanks! works beautifully! May I ask what's \g<0>? sorry I'm new to regex

Comment: @AshleyLiu `\g` stands for `group`. Regex allows you to search for patterns or words in groups. You must have come across something like this in django urls - `(?P<slug>\w+)`. The pattern inside parenthesis `(...)` is a named capture group and `<slug>` is the name of this group. If you want to access the matched value of `slug`, you can use `\g<slug>`. In my answer, we're just compiling the regex pattern using the search term. So we haven't used any groups. However, regex will still keep the matched words in group number `0` by default. And we can use the matched words by calling `\g<0>`.

Comment: @AshleyLiu If we had multiple groups in the pattern, for example like this - `pattern = re.compile("(korean) (war)")`, then `"korean"` will be in group 1 and `"war"` will be in group 2. So, we'd use `\g<1>` and `\g<2>` to access them. And `\g<0>` will return both of them as regex keeps all the matches in group 0 by default. This document explains is better with examples: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! Do you happen to know why this filter always misses the first time the keyword occurs? It highlights all the keywords except for the first time when it appears. For example, if a sentence is "my cake is a cake from a cake shop", it would only highlight the second and third "cake" but not the first one

Comment: @AshleyLiu I tested this in a python shell right now and it's matching every occurrence. You can see the behaviour here: https://regex101.com./r/DMZ37Z/1. See the "Substitution" panel.